# Can't use ng2-smart-table in angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-smart-table

Steps to create a new `angular 2` project:

> ng new myapp
>   cd myapp
>   npm i ng2-smart-table --save

And change the `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';

// ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...

    Ng2SmartTableModule,

    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [ ... ]
})
// ...
```

Then I got the following error message when I try to run `ng serve`:

> ERROR in /Users/Public/myapp/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/src/ng2-smart-table/lib/data-source/server/server.data-source.ts (70,12): Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable' is not a class derived from 'Observable'.)

Then the whole project stops running even the part which caused the problem is actually not used at all.

By the way, my specs:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
node: 7.5.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.6
@angular/compiler: 2.4.6
@angular/core: 2.4.6
@angular/forms: 2.4.6
@angular/http: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.6
@angular/router: 3.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.6
```

Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Fixed the issue.

Fixed the issue.

ng2-smart-table's package.json contains this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ng2-completer": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2"
  },
```

but rxjs should be here instead:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2"
  },
```

Delete the `rxjs` folder inside `node_modules` of `ng2-smart-table`. Rerun `npm i`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any error here. it's just clean app generated by angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
[image: angular]

Comment: I'm running node 7.5 with angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.30 in mac. Got this problem in a newly created project. What is your node version?

Comment: because version 28, 29 have some bugs, try to install version 26, i think so.

Comment: Same problem. What is your @angular/core version?

Comment: 2.4.6 latest version